# Pass class method to const char * parameter

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

In Qt QShortcut has such constructor

```
QShortcut(const QKeySequence& key, QWidget *parent,
          const char *member = 0, const char *ambiguousMember = 0,
          Qt::ShortcutContext context = Qt::WindowShortcut);
```

As far as I understand from documentation I can pass a method to the third parameter instead of using connect to signal activated. But how can I pass method there? Using

```
QShortcut* sh = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Alt, Qt::Key_1), this, &OnShortcut);
```

or

```
QShortcut* sh = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Alt, Qt::Key_1), this, &MyClass::OnShortcut);
```

gives errors

error: no matching function for call to 'QShortcut::QShortcut(QKeySequence, KeyPressProcessing* const, void (*)())'

Comment: You can try to use `SLOT(OnShortcut())` instead of `&OnShortcut`.

Comment: @vahancho thanks, works. But can you pls explain me a little bit why it is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `SLOT(OnShortcut())` instead of `&OnShortcut` because the `QShortcut` class constructor requires `const char *`as the second and third arguments and not the pointer to a function. Thus, Qt has dedicated conversion macro `SLOT` that accepts the function signature as an argument and converts it in the form that suitable for establishing connection.